# How do I manually slide a carousel?

Tags: javascript

I am using jCarousel as below:

```
jcarousel_add('#jcarousel',
  array('vertical' => false, 'scroll' => 3, 'horizontalDirection' => $direction, 'initCallback' => 'slCarousel_initCallback')
);
```

How can I manually slide the carousel?

When I run `jQuery("#jcarousel").jcarousel().next();`, in Firebug I get the following:

```
>>> jQuery("#jcarousel").jcarousel().next();
[]
```

I have tried this as well in the Firebug console:

```
var carousel = jQuery("#jcarousel").data('jcarousel');
//alert (carousel);
carousel.next();
```

I got the following:

```
>>> var carousel = jQuery("#jcarousel").data('jcarousel'); carousel.next()
TypeError: carousel is undefined
```

Comment: Are you using jcarousel_add() correctly? According to module README.txt, the first parameter is a class name, not ID.

Comment: it is okay for both... you can use jcarousel_add('#id') or jcarousel_add('.class') ,,, however, i tried both of them and got the same !! :(

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by creating a global variable, and then assigning the value of the carousel to it.

```
var global_jc="";
function slCarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
  global_jc=carousel;
  // ...
}
```

Wherever I want to use `next()`, I use the following code:

```
global_jc.next();
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [jCarousel Docs](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Accessing-The-Jcarousel-Instance) you need to use

```
var carousel = jQuery("#jcarousel").data('jcarousel');
```

You can then use controls (as demonstrated at [this example](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_controls.html))

```
carousel.next()
```

Comment: I have tried this already in firebug and it gives
>>> var carousel = jQuery("#jcarousel").data('jcarousel'); carousel.next()
TypeError: carousel is undefined
and by alerting carousrl i got "undefined"